Why does bun execute this simple code 2 times as long as node.js?
I saw how fast bun was and generated some random code to compare node.js and bun. I expected bun would execute much faster than node.js but bun takes two times as long as node.js.
[Code]
// 2. Matrix Multiplication Test
function multiplyMatrices(matrixA, matrixB) {
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < matrixA.length; i++) {
        result[i] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < matrixB[0].length; j++) {
            let sum = 0;
            for (let k = 0; k < matrixA[0].length; k++) {
                sum += matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j];
            }
            result[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Generate matrices and run multiplication
const matrixSize = 2000;
const matrixA = Array.from({ length: matrixSize }, () => Array(matrixSize).fill(1));
const matrixB = Array.from({ length: matrixSize }, () => Array(matrixSize).fill(1));
console.time("Matrix Multiplication");
multiplyMatrices(matrixA, matrixB);
console.timeEnd("Matrix Multiplication");

[Result]
% node node.js
Matrix Multiplication: 22.287s
User@user /Users/User/dev/temp/test
% bun node.js
[47.58s] Matrix Multiplication

Do you have any clues why bun outperformed node.js with this code?

bun did not outperform node.js according to the results you posted. Rather, it turned out more like your title says; bun took 2 times as long as node.js to run the same code. But bun is at version 1.1.33 in its latest version, whereas Node.js is at 23.1.0 in its latest version. You don't mention what versions you're comparing.

nodejs and bun use different javascript engines. Different javascript engines have different performance characteristics. Some code runs faster in bun than nodejs, and some code runs faster in nodejs than bun. You've written code that runs faster in nodejs
